# Octave, statistics package over Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, statistics, octave

I'm trying to install the Octave statistics package over Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, but I can't.

I installed successfully the package of Octave using:

```
sudo apt-get install octave
```

Next, I try to install the statistics package using:

```
sudo apt-get install octave-statistics
```

But says:

> The following packages have unmet dependencies:  octave-statistics :
>   Depends: octave-io (>= 1.0.18) but it is not going to be installed

Of course I tried installig octave-io using:

```
sudo apt-get install octave-io
```

After that, I get this message:

> The following packages have unmet dependencies:  octave-io 
>   Depends: liboctave3 but it is not going to be installed 
>   E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Next, I try to install **liboctave3** using:

```
sudo apt-get install liboctave3
```

But I receive the next message:

> The following packages will be REMOVED:   octave 
>   The following NEW packages will be installed:   liboctave3

It tries to remove octave.... but I need octave....

What can I do?

Comment: I never used Ubuntu (I'm a Debian GNU/Linux user) but I think you should follow the instructions [on the wiki](http://wiki.octave.org/Octave_for_Debian_systems#Octave.27s_Personal_Package_Archive_.28PPA.29_for_Ubuntu) to install it using the [PPA](https://launchpad.net/~octave/+archive/ubuntu/stable)

Comment: That looks like a very weird Ubuntu packaging bug. Are you sure you are installing from the Ubuntu repository? Or have you enabled some PPA that also provides Octave and Octave packages?

Comment: While I appreciate that one can do programming in octave this doesn't look like a programming problem to me, but rather a package management one; thus it really belongs to https://superuser.com or https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

Have you by any chance managed to resolve this issue?

I am having exactly the same problem on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. Attempting to install `octave-io` using

```
sudo apt-get install octave-io
```

leads to a message

```
octave-io: Depends: liboctave3 but it is not going to be installed E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Using

```
sudo apt-get install liboctave3
```

comes back with a message that `octave` will be removed.

Quite puzzled too now.

**Update: 2018-01-14**

Turns out there are some dependency issues if octave is installed from the octave ppa. Installing from standard Ubuntu repository doesn't lead to any problems. It's an older version but it works.

The following should work if one comes across the problem above:

```
sudo apt-get purge octave
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:octave/stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install octave
```

Answer (score 0):

You, probably, should update your installation. I dimly remember something like this around LTS 16.04.0

Right now I have on my system

```
user@Lub16LTS: ~$ cat /etc/lsb-release 
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=16.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=xenial
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS"
user@Lub16LTS: ~$
```

And, with `octave` installed

```
user@Lub16LTS: ~$ sudo apt install octave-statistics
```

works like a charm

```
user@Lub16LTS: ~$ sudo apt install octave-statistics
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  ant ant-optional libapache-poi-java libapache-pom-java libcommons-codec-
  java libcommons-logging-java libcommons-parent-java libdom4j-java libjaxen-
  java libjdom1-java
  libjexcelapi-java libjopendocument-java liblog4j1.2-java libxerces2-java 
  libxml-commons-external-java libxml-commons-resolver1.1-java libxmlbeans-java libxom-java
  libxpp2-java libxpp3-java octave-io
Suggested packages:
  ant-doc ant-gcj default-jdk | java-compiler | java-sdk ant-optional-gcj 
  antlr javacc junit jython libbcel-java libbsf-java libcommons-net-java 
  libgnumail-java
  libjaxp1.3-java libjdepend-java libjsch-java liboro-java libregexp-java 
  libxalan2-java libapache-poi-java-doc libavalon-framework-java libcommons-logging-java-doc
  libexcalibur-logkit-java libdom4j-java-doc libjdom1-java-doc liblog4j1.2-java-doc libxerces2-java-doc libxerces2-java-gcj libxml-commons-resolver1.1-java-doc
  libxom-java-doc
The following NEW packages will be installed:
   ....
0 upgraded, 22 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Answer (score 0):

install it using this commands:

```
 sudo apt-get install flatpak
 flatpak remote-add --if-not-exists flathub https://flathub.org/repo/flathub.flatpakrepo
 flatpak install flathub org.octave.Octave
```